# How to hide ajax modal popup extender when clicking browser's back button?

Tags: asp.net

I have shown one confirmation message using ajax modal pop up extender during button click in server side in asp.net. After showing that confirmation message, when i click browser's back button, the same pop up confirmation message coming again. How to hide that pop up message when i click browser's back button?

My Code is

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlInterfaceDetails" Style="display: none;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Confirmation Message" Font-Bold="true"
                    Font-Size="10pt" Style="color: White; font-family: Sans-Serif Verdana Arial"></asp:Label>
                <table>
                    <tr style="height: 35px">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <b><span style="color: Black;">Data Saved Successfully.</span></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 35px">
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirmClose" Text="Close" ToolTip="Close" Width="65px"
                                OnClick="btnConfirmClose_Click" CssClass="buttonOrangebg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mpeInterfaceDetails" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pnlInterfaceDetails" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 
    $('your behaviorid').hide();
});
```

If you want to get fancier you could detect the back history but this will hide it anytime the page unloads. This is before unload which if you wanted you could also add a prompt in there to make sure they want to click back.

The above requires Jquery.

Comment: origin1tech:Thank you for your reply. This code not working properly.Give any other solution for this problem. I have shown this pop up message during saving operation. After saving the data, i want to go back to previous page through browser's back button click..

Comment: don't know your app but the above does work as to hiding the modal. I'm certain of it. You can also use 'unload' event as well. Using webforms as you are your "viewstate" will maintain all the data so saving then using back is at least in most cases a bad idea. Why? because you could end up with duplicate posts. Typically what you'd do is a redirect. Response.Redirect('/your url here');

Comment: add to that when using the back button the page remembers viewstate as I was saying so in order to prevent that last state you'd either have to monkey with the viewstate or add a session var or something to detect that it is the second time hitting the page (e.g. the back button). If you want to try that let me know and I'll edit with an example using session or custom viewstate.

Comment: First I bind the details in grid view with respect to Search criteria in one page. After clicking hyper link available inside grid view, the page will redirect to edit page. In that page i am saving the data. After saving the data I have to send email through another button click.That email button is only enabled after save button click. If there is no any other action available in that page, i definitely will use response.redirect. That is why I am retaining that page details after save operation. But modal popup extender shown again and again whenever I click back button of browser.

Comment: I would expose the mail sending method after the edit is saved then. Use back doesn't make sense to me. If need be do like I said and store some val in a session var which after redirect you can check and make that button avail when it hits the page the second time. Once checked if true clear it. That would be how I'd handle that.

Comment: I got some ideas from your suggestions. Thank you for your suggestions.